# Imagemagick convert multiple images to pdf size

Tags: php, linux, pdf, pdf-generation, imagemagick

For a project I am running ImageMagick to convert several images (all of the same size 960x570) into a single PDF.

The command I'm running is:

```
convert *.jpg pdf/export.pdf
```

Since the images are all the same size I expect each PDF page to be equal in size but this is not the case as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: example screenshot]

This is bit annoying since I don't know how I can force the size of each PDF page to be the same.

I tested the PDF on both an android device, ubuntu pdf reader and adobe reader and they all show the different sizes.

Thanks for helping!

**EDIT1:**
After testing out a few more things as suggested by Marc B and Basti I managed to put the same size on the JPG (uploaded) images.

The problem still persists with the images that are generated using webkit2png (Python script that converts a webpage/html file to an image). After trying (almost?) everything in the convert command I can't get these generated images to shop up properly in the PDF as you can see below:

[image]

**Any help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Check the DPI settings inside the jpg. Most pdf converters will honor that. e.g. a 900x700 image at 100dpi will be 9"x7" in the pdf, but only but ony 3"x2.3" at 300dpi

Comment: Thanks for helping, please see Edit1 in my questions with an update regarding the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution:

I needed to add the following options to convert the image saved from webkit2png:

```
-density 960x570 -units PixelsPerInch
```

I hope this helps other people out too in the future ;)

Answer (score 2):

After a few seconds of using google, I found this:

`-size <geometry>   width and height of image`

Example given by them:

```
$ convert -size 320x85 canvas:none -font Bookman-DemiItalic -pointsize 72 \ 
-draw "text 25,60 'Magick'" -channel RGBA -blur 0x6 -fill darkred -stroke magenta \ 
-draw "text 20,55 'Magick'" fuzzy-magick.png
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Comment: Thanks for helping, please see Edit1 in my questions with an update regarding the issue I'm having.

Comment: My bed is the DPI issue Marc B described. Did you compare the DPI values for your JPGs?